# Can I manually adjust a Plane Track?

Tags: tracking

I use 4 points to create a plane track.
It works for half of the clip but at a point the movements are difficult to track and the plane starts to wobble.
I would like to manually correct the plane movement, on a frame by frame basis, a bit like it works for masking.
Unfortunately, anytime I move a corner of the plane, on a specific frame, it readjust the position of the plane for the whole clip.

Is there a way to take manual control over the plane track ?

Comment: you can manually re-position the trackers used for the plane track.

Comment: @cegaton yes but that doesn't readjust the plane immediately. I would like to see the plane edges adjusted in real time.

Comment: Indeed the plane track is not interactive. The plane track will only be as good as the tracking. So manually reposition the trackers that are slipping off (or re-track using other options) and then recreate the plane track.

Comment: @cegaton Is there another way to create and move a plane, frame by frame? There must be something in the 3D tools, but I don't know where and what to search for.

Comment: you can export the trackers as empties and use those to control the deformation on a plane (mapped with an image). That was the old way of doing it before the plane track. Using empties as hooks you can have total control on the deformation using keyframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blender 2.9+ there is an option for *Auto Keyframing* plane track corners.

If you press <kbd>N</kbd> while in the tracking scene and open the *Track* tab, there is a dropdown for the *Plane Track* which allows you to set Auto Keyframes for plane track corners.

You can make manual adjustments without having to export the trackers to empties and hook them.